# How to use the "current" in jCoverflip so that the current item is always in the middle of a dynamically generated list?

Tags: jquery, image, slider, carousel

I wanna create a thumbnail carousel with jCoverflip. I know how to choose the current item with numbers - it's pretty simple:

```
current: 0
```

That would pick the first item of the list. But i have a dynamically generated list with thumbnails and want to pick the middle one as the current. The jCoverflip documentation [link here](http://www.jcoverflip.com/documentation/advance-customization)

doesnt really help because there are no examples. Does anyone of you know how to pick the list element in the middle? It cant be that complicated. It has to be something like:

```
current: $('.clips > li').length()/2
```

but i don't know the correct syntax. Please help me if you know!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for getting the length for the list is

```
$('#flip').jcoverflip('length');
```

but this is only available once the .jcoverflip has been instantiated on your list and you need this value when you instantiate .jcoverflip on your list, so it's a bit of a catch 22 as I see it.

What I did to solve it was to get the number of li items from #flip like this

```
var middle = Math.round($('#flip li').length / 2);
```

and then I instantiated .jcoverflip

```
$('#flip').jcoverflip({
    current: middle
});
```

I used Math.round in case the number of items in the list is an odd number. Jcoverflip won't work if you put in a float as current.